# Obtain residual diagnostic plots from rms package ols() function

Tags: r, linear-regression, diagnostics

How do you obtain residual diagnostic plots from an `ols()` object? normally if using `glm()` or `lm()`, I'd just do `plot(lm())`, but `plot(ols())` gives an error.

My code is:

```r
fit <- ols(y ~ rcs(x1,4)*x2, data=data, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
plot(fit)
```

The error message I receive is

> Error in match.arg(type) :
> 'arg' should be one of “ordinary”, “score”, “dfbeta”, “dfbetas”, “dffit”, “dffits”, “hat”, “hscore”

Answer (score 1):

The `ols` object does inherit from the `lm` object,

```
class(rcsLogFit)
## [1] "ols" "rms" "lm"
```

but I was unable to gets `stats:::lm()` to work without the error noted here.

A quick workaround is to make a copy that forgets its `rms`-specific classes:

```
rcsLogCopy <- rcsLogFit
class(rcsLogCopy) <- "lm"
```

and then

```
plot(rcsLogCopy)
```

works fine. I suppose you could do this directly on the original instead.

Answer (score 0):

Laboriously (but flexibly), you need to compute residuals and estimates (using `resid()` and `fitted()`) and bind them into your data frame, then use plotting package like ggplot2 or lattice to create the plots yourself. Harrell gives examples at bottom of p. 153 of the 2nd edition of his book that describes the use of this package in detail.

As a quick and dirty alternative, you can fit a version using conventional functions (e.g. `lm()`) and `plot()` will return the usual diagnostic plots. Things like `rcs()` will work with many of the base fitting functions.